# Cannot find function getValue in object Nom.Candidat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set a pdf sending by email. I want the email subject contain :
Vérifications pré-emploi complétées + Candidate Name.
Candidate name is a range named Nom.Candidat

So, what's am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

```
function emailAsPDF() {
  var emailAddress=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var mess="Voulez-vous envoyer votre rapport  à l'adresse : " + emailAddress;
  var ans= Browser.msgBox("Courriel", mess, Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (ans===Browser.Buttons.NO){return;}
  var mess="Votre rapport a été envoyé à l'adresse : " + emailAddress;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Recherche");
  //var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var CandidateName=ss.getRangeByName("Nom.Candidat".getValue());
  var emailSubject="Vérifications pré-emploi complétées" + CandidateName;
  var emailMessage="Bonjour," + "\n\n" + "J’ai le plaisir de vous informer que les vérifications sont complétées pour le candidat indiqué au tableau de résultats pré-emploi suivant:" + "\n\n" + "Bonne journée !";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//.getSheetByName("Formation");
  var sheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Recherche");
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);
  var sheetNames=newSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  var blob = newSpreadsheet.getAs('application/pdf').setName(spreadsheet.getName());
  var folderID = parentFolder(); // Folder id to save the PDF
  Logger.log(folderID);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailMessage,{attachments:[pdfFile]});
  //DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
  DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFile.getId()).setTrashed(true);
  Browser.msgBox("Courriel", mess, Browser.Buttons.OK); 
}


function parentFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
  var ParentFolder= file.getParents();
  while ( ParentFolder.hasNext() ) {
    var folder = ParentFolder.next();
    folderID=folder.getId();
     Logger.log(folderID);
  }
  return folderID;
}

function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
  var ParentFolder= file.getParents();
  var folder = ParentFolder.next();
   Logger.log(folder);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bracket is in the wrong place, try:

```
var CandidateName=ss.getRangeByName("Nom.Candidat").getValue();
```